# How to call an xslt transform into an xsl stylesheet

Tags: xslt

I have written an xslt that reads some xml file names and does some operations on them.
I use a for-each to work them one-by-one. I have each path inside a parameter $path.

But now I would like to output the result of applying an external stylesheet to those files. I would write something like

```
<div> <something like xsl-transform($extern-xslt,$path)> </div>
```

to have the result tree of the transformation inside the main html output.
It is possible?

Comment: Good Question! (+1), See my answer for the only complete solution at this moment and for a complete, working code example. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `document()` XPath function to load an external XML file. This returns a node-set which can be parsed with a `<xml:apply-templates>` call. Including an external stylesheet can be accomplished by using an `<xsl:include>` tag.

```
<xsl:include href="$external"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document($path)"/>
```

See also [the documentation for `document()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp)

Answer (score 2):

You could import the external stylesheet to your main stylesheet with [`xsl:import`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#import), and then just apply templates to that external XML file, which you can load with the [`document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) function.

```
<div><xsl:apply-templates select="document($path)"/></div>
```

If the templates in the external stylesheet would collide with the templates in the main stylesheet, you can use a different [mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes) for them.

Answer (score 0):

> I have written an xslt that reads
>   some xml file names and does some
>   operations on them. I use a for-each
>   to work them one-by-one. I have each
>   path inside a parameter $path.
>
> But now I would like to output the
>   result of applying an external
>   stylesheet to those files

**The solution consists of these ingredients**:

1. Use the standard XSLT [**`document()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function to load and access the external XML document.
2. Import the external stylesheet, using an [**`<xsl:import>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-import) instruction.
3. The templates in the external stylesheet must be in a special [**mode**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes), not used by the primary stylesheet.
4. At the place where the result of the "external transformation" is wanted, issue `<xsl:apply-templates>` selecting the necessary nodes of the external document (usually the root node `/`, or the top element `/*`). The mode, specified on the `<xsl:apply-templates>` should be the same as the mode used in the external stylesheet.

**Here is a small, simplified example** (No external stylesheet is imported, the "external document" is embedded in the stylesheet, and no mode is used):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:my="my:my"
>
<!--  <xsl:import href="myExternal.xsl"/> -->
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <my:div>
      <h2>Weather</h2>
      <p >It will be raining today</p>
    </my:div>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="insertContents">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/my:div/*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<html>
  <h1>Today's News </h1>
  <insertContents/>
</html>
```

**the desired result is produced**:

```
<html>

   <h1>Today's News </h1>

   <h2 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="my:my">Weather</h2>
   <p xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="my:my">It will be raining today</p>

</html>
```

**Note** that the extraneous namespaces above are only due to the simplifications of this example -- they will not be generated if the external XML document were in its own file.